# R : Format the text file output

Tags: r

Can anyone help me on how to format the text file like the format in the image below?
I am using R 2.12.2 so the functions of higher version can't be use.

I have tried using `writeLine`, `sprintf` and `capture.output`, but none of it works.. :(

```
f_output <- file("sample.txt")
writeLines("D8060WK2LA MET1_PAT__ mpy Trend [5300 2450 2050]\n",f_output)
capture.output(summary(lm_out),file="sample.txt",append=T)
capture.output(anova_out,file="sample.txt",append=T)
close(f_output)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying `sink`, as in:

```
sink('sample.txt') # open sink
# run all of your code
sink() # close sink
```

And you should get what you want.